# Codable Encoder required for NSManagedObject subclass?

Tags: swift, core-data

`func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws` is required for the `Codable` protocol.

Is there any reason to implement this in your code for an `NSManagedObject` subclass?

Is there something I'm missing, or should a fatal error simply be returned from this function.

The example subclass is the same for all such subclasses

```
@objc(Commit)
public class Commit: NSManagedObject, Codable {

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        // Note encode is blank here
    }
    
    required convenience public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        // return the context from the decoder userinfo dictionary
        guard let contextUserInfoKey = CodingUserInfoKey.context,
        let managedObjectContext = decoder.userInfo[contextUserInfoKey] as? NSManagedObjectContext,
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Commit", in: managedObjectContext)
        else {
            fatalError("decode failure")
        }
        // Super init of the NSManagedObject
        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        do {
            sha = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .sha)
            url = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .url)
            html_url = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .html_url)
            gitcommit = try values.decode(GitCommit.self, forKey: .gitcommit)
        } catch {
            print ("error")
        }
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case sha = "sha"
        case gitcommit = "commit"
        case url = "url"
        case html_url = "html_url"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adopting `Codable` implies that you want to decode **and** encode the objects.

If **you** have no reason to encode the class adopt only `Decodable`